# Outer Joining two List to generate a new List in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-stream

I'm trying to find a way to join two List of objects with two unique attributes to produce a new List of Object.

**Users Class**

```
public class Users {

    String id;

    String name;

    String gender;

}
```

Adding some data here

```
List<Users> userList=new ArrayList<Users>();
userList.add(new Users("1","AA","Male"));
userList.add(new Users("2","BB","Male"));
userList.add(new Users("3","CC","Female"));
```

**Academics Class**

```
public class Academics {

    String id;

    String name;

    String grade;

    String professional;

}
```

Adding some data here

```
List<Academics> academicsList=new ArrayList<Academics>();
academicsList.add(new Academics("1","AA","A","Doctor"));
academicsList.add(new Academics("2","BB","B","Carpenter"));
academicsList.add(new Academics("3","CC","C","Engineer"));
```

**My Profile**

```
Public class Profile {

String id;

String name;

String gender;

String grade;

String professional;

}
```

Here I need to calculate the List by Outer joining the UserList and academicsList with the 2 common attributes of `id` and `name`

I do need to do this as a bulk operation instead of going with any For/While loops one by one.

Is there is any way to use [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) to achieve this?

**Update 1:**
The Joining here would be like Outer-Joining where some id would not be present in academics but it would be present in Users.
In such case We need to show empty values for the grade/professional in Profile List(s)

Thanks in advance,
Jay

Comment: What do you mean by joining two lists of different types? What's the type of the resulting list? Or do you mean something like 'find all users who are also academics'?

Comment: @sprinter he wants to combine UserList and AcademicsList to form a resulting list of my profile.

Comment: @saif ahmad : The problem miss detail. What type of join do you want ? If you want inner, your resulting list will be populated only if you find same id in both input lists. But if you want outer join, your list will also be filled if an id is found only in  one of the two input lists. And that change everything to the algorithm to use. So sprinter question is appropriate.

Comment: @saifahmad I still don't understand that. `Profile` has several fields that don't exist in the other classes. What will the value of those fields be for the newly created objects?

Comment: @amanin : sorry I missed it. I updated the question. I need to perform the OuterJoin here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would make sense to convert one of the input Lists to a Map, in order to quickly correlate between entries of the first and second Lists.

```
Map<String,Users> userByID = userList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Users::getID,Function.identity));
```

Now you can Stream over the elements of the second List:

```
List<Profile> profiles = 
    academicsList.stream()
                 .map(a -> {
                     Profile p = null;
                     Users u = userByID.get(a.getID());
                     if (u != null) {
                         p = new Profile();
                         // now set all the Profile fields based on the properties
                         // of the Users instance (u) and the Academics instance (a)
                     }
                     return p;
                 })
                 .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Given your additional requirement, you should create a `Map` for the second `List` and `Stream` the first `List`:

```
Map<String,Academics> academicsByID = userList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Academics::getID,Function.identity));

List<Profile> profiles = 
    userList.stream()
                 .map(u -> {
                     Profile p = new Profile ();
                     Academics a = academicsByID.get(u.getID());
                     // now set all the Profile fields based on the properties
                     // of the Users instance (u) and the Academics instance (a)
                     // (if available)
                     return p;
                 })
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Your answer is working great,but i missed the information in my question regarding the type of join. As default this was good for inner join.but i would need to perform *`Outer Join`* where the `profile` needs to show null for the missing attributes in `academics`. P.S The source of truth in `Users` class

Comment: @Jayendran You can make a simple change - create a Map from the second list (academicsList) and stream over the first list (userList). And in the Stream pipeline, create the Profile even if the Academics instance is not found in the Map.

Comment: You nailed it man. ! It works perfectly. Just one question.You used `Id` alone for the identity. But the actual data has the uniqueness of combing both `id` and `name`. Is there is a way to include the `name` as a business key.

Comment: @Jayendran You can concatenate the ID and name and use that as the key of the Map. Instead of `Users::getID`, write `u->u.getID()+u.getName()`. Then change `academicsByID.get(u.getID())` to `academicsByID.get(u.getID()+u.getName());`